# Custom Font Monodevelop

Tags: c#, fonts, gtk, cross-platform, monodevelop

How would I use a custom ttf in a gtk2.12 application in monodevelop? I've currently got the font inside the project as an embedded resource, and I'm not sure how to turn it into a Pango.FontDescription without installing it on the host system.

I'm trying to code with cross-platform compatibility, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I don't think it's possible as you describe. But you could install it locally when you run the program for the first time. On a Unix system you can install fonts into `~/.fonts` and they will be available to Pango, and I expect that Pango looks for something similar on Windows.

Comment: Good suggestion, I could probably open a FileStream, get the font stream, and write it to .fonts. What about Windows? The only resources are embedding a font using a PrivateFontCollection, but that uses Windows Forms. :)

Comment: Check if your Windows build of Pango uses Fontconfig; if so, there should be a `fonts.conf` file somewhere that you can point to a local directory with your fonts. If not, then I don't know.